# How to extract hooks from a Wordpress Theme Framework

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay I am into Wordpress child theming, now I want to know if theres a php or Wordpress code that can list down all the Wordpress hooks from a Wordpress framework.

I got the list of hooks for Genesis WP framework, what if I my client want to change the Wordpress Framework like Thesis, etc.. How will I know the list of its Hooks so I can easily create a child theme for it?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Search the theme for `do_action` and `add_action`. Any half-decent text editor should be able to find these strings within a group of files.

Comment: Building on the suggestion made by @mevius I'd also look for `apply_filters`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice guys , I see its really painful to learn hooks for every new Wordpress framework. I wish wordpress would create a function for this.